# Can I use recovery disks from one computer to upgrade my other computer?

Tags: upgrade

I have 2 computers. One is running XP and the others Windows 7. Can I upgrade the old XP with recovery disks from the Windows 7 computer?  Thanks.........

Comment: The recovery disks are to repair windows 7 not install it.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery disks tend to be specific to the model that they're from - there's various checks for activation so a system that came with windows 7 will automatically be activated (but not the one with XP). It'll also install drivers for that system configuration.

In short, no, that would not work at all. You'll need to buy a retail or upgrade licence and use the key from that and the appropriate media to install instead.

If the model had for some strange reason come with XP and 7, and the systems are identical it MIGHT work, though, you'll likely be violating your licence.